# Unable to update object data using sails.config.bootstrap

Tags: node.js, sails.js

I'm unable to update an object upon lifting a sails app. I think something is wrong with scope but I'm not sure.

config/cron.js

```
const updaterService = require('../api/services/updater');

module.exports.cron = {
  Update: {
    schedule: '0 * * * * *',
    onTick: function () {
      console.log('You will see this every second');
      updaterService.updateObj();
    }
  }
};
```

api/services/updater.js

```
const rp = require('request-promise');

const testObj = {
  data: '',
};

const showData = () => {
  sails.log.info(testObj);
};

const updateObj = async () => {
    try {
      const updateResponse = await rp(updateOpts);
      testObj.data = updateResponse.body.data;
sails.log.info(testObj);
    } catch (updateErr) {
      sails.log.error(`${updateErr.statusCode}: ${updateErr}`);
    }
};
```

What I get when I call showData() is that there is no update to the object (second line). But when updateObj is called from config/cron, it seems like it has been updated though (first line):

```
{ data: 'some data here' }
{ data: '' }
```

Comment: Why are you doing this in bootstrap? Use [sails-hook-cron](https://www.npmjs.com/package/sails-hook-cron).

Comment: I didn't really know where else to start the job. I'll check out sails-hook-cron

Comment: @Glen, it did the same - there is no update to the object.

Comment: What version of Sails are you using? Can you update your question with the full service code? And add the code you have added to cron.js in config folder?

Comment: @Glen, updated. I'm using 0.12.14

Comment: I will post an answer

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, let's look at services with SailsJS, particularly in versions < 1 where they have since been replaced with helpers.

To create a service, there is a strict filenaming convention. Make sure your service's filename ends in Service.js. The first part of this filename will be used as the globally-accessible variable name for the service.
In your example, this would mean renaming the file to UpdaterService.js.

Next, services within Sails export some reusable funtionality. In your example, this will most likely be your function call to updateObj. I'm not sure why you are using request-promise for a scheduled (batch) job, so for extra simplicity, I will just use request. If not already in your library, you will need to install request - `npm install request`.

This is a complete example service below, I've cut out the stuff that does not make sense to me from your code.

`UpdaterService.js.`

```
const request = require('request');

module.exports = {

    updateObj : () => {
        // I am assuming updateOpts is some URL with serialized params, so let's just call it url
        let url = "https://www.example.com?foo=bar";
        request(url, function (error, response, body) {
            if(error){
                sails.log.error(error);
            }
            if(body && body.data){
                sails.log.info(body.data);
            }
        });
    }
};
```

And here is an example cron file calling the above service every day at 12 midday. No need require the service as it is automatically globally-accessible if named correctly.

`config/cron.js`

```
module.exports.cron = {
    dailyScheduler: {
        schedule: '0 0 12 * * *',
        onTick: function() {
            UpdaterService.updateObj();
        }
    }
};
```

Comment: It doesn't address the issue where the testObj is not being updated though.

I have pretty much the same code but I need to assign the object with new values. (Updating API keys after they expire for example). Sorry for being unable to give actual code - it's a homework assignment.

Comment: To be honest, that doesn't really make sense. You have a scheduled job that does a specific thing, e.g. check if an API key is expired. Using the above request code, I make a call to a remote API and the response is your API key is outdated. Well in the `if(body && body.data){` I handle what ever I need to do next, setting some variable, particularly a const variable which by definition should not change makes no sense.